# How to call getChangedCells method for jQGrid CellEdit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I can get the changed cell/row values using the following:

```
var ret = $(”#grid”).getChangedCells('all'); // Return Rows
```

or

```
var ret = $(”#grid”).getChangedCells('dirty'); // Returns the changed cells.
```

Comment: is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: I don't think so, but at least he answers the question he asked in the question header.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jqGrid docs for getChangedCells](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing):

> Returns an array of the changed cells depending on method (string, default 'all'). When 'all' this method returns all the changed rows; when 'dirty' returns only the changed cells with the id of the row

So I am confused why `$("#grid").getChangedCells('dirty')` does not meet your needs. Perhaps you can elaborate further?