# How to use getChangedCells method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

I found that getChangedCells method is somehow applicable to the application that I am building right now.

Can someone show me on how to use getChangedCells method?

Thanks

Regards

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var temp= $("#grid").getChangedCells('all') // Return Rows
```

or

```
var temp= $("#grid").getChangedCells('dirty') / Returns the changed cells.
```

Also try looking at the [official docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing) as @ozczecho mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Check this [out](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing). Official documentation. Or a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147157/how-to-call-getchangedcells-method-for-jqgrid-celledit).